# Ruby: how can Enumerator be used in the following example?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I can't seem to go beyond using Enumerators in a trivial way.
Maybe it's actually more limited than I realize.

Here is an example where I thought Enumerators would be handy, but couldn't implement them:

Let array = [0,  1, 2, "+", 4].

I'm interested in creating the following Enumerator-behavior:

1. iterate through the array
2. yield all objects that are not "+"
3. if it is a "+", delete that element and the previous two elements,
   yield their sum, and reset the enumeration sequence to the
   beginning.

Maybe the problem is that I can't "delete" something that has already been yielded? In other words, I can't un-yield? I'm interested in this behavior because of its ability to rewind the sequence at any given position after mutating the array (which messes up the order of iteration).

Comment: What if you had `[0, 1, 2, '+', '+']`?  Would that end up as `[3]` or is it not possible or ... ?

Comment: That should end up as [3], but that's outside the scope of what I'm interested in. I'm really just interested in what Enumerators could do, and it doesn't seem like they can do a whole much to me.

Comment: Enumerators are more about chaining things (`a.each_with_index.map { ... }`) than they are about moving back and forth. Just because you can move forward doesn't mean that you can move backward, consider a non-seekable input stream as a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

[Enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html) does not have a `previous` method, it does not allow you to skip values while iterating and it does not have a method to delete elements.

So I think that you can't do what you want with the exact workflow you posted although I am sure it is possible to create the behaviour you seek when it is possible to deviate from your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Summary - this option seems to meet your criteria as expressed:

```
[0, 1, 2, "+", 4].inject([]) { |n,e| n << (e == "+" ? n.pop(2).reduce(:+) : e) }
# => [0, 3, 4]
```

Here was my thinking on it...

Option 1:

Use `each_with_index` and that way you can identify the previous elements easily.

```
array.each_with_index do |element, index|
  your_logic_here
end
```

Option 2:

Or to avoid mutating the array you could just simply build a new one like this:

```
new_array = []
array.each do |element|
  if element == "+"
    ele_sum = new_array.pop(2)
    new_array << (ele_sum.reduce :+)
  else
    new_array << element
  end
end
```

And if you don't find it confusing you can combine the two lines in the if statement to:

```
new_array << new_array.pop(2).reduce(:+)
```

Or if you're okay with the ternary operator shorten the whole thing to:

```
def some_function(array)
  new_array = []
  array.each { |element| new_array << (element == "+" ? new_array.pop(2).reduce(:+) : element) }
end

> array = [0, 1, 2, "+", 4]
> some_function(array)
# => [0, 3, 4]
```

Works and tested in irb

...or use inject of course then you can do it all inline:

```
array.inject([]) { |new_array, element| new_array << (element == "+" ? new_array.pop(2).reduce(:+) : element) }

[0, 1, 2, "+", 4].inject([]) { |n,e| n << (e == "+" ? n.pop(2).reduce(:+) : e) }
# => [0, 3, 4]
```

But I prefer the expanded version for readability

Comment: How do you propose to make the 1 and 2 disappear when you hit `'+'`?

Comment: @muistooshort I may be wrong but isn't changing (deleting) self (elements of array) in this case bad idea, as it may show unexpected behavior?

Comment: Well writing the code to delete at index-1,-2 should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Yes you can build and return a new array if you'd prefer.